# Any way to see my PC and Macbook's folders using iPad?

Tags: ipad

Is there a way to do that?

The only way i can think of is to use dropbox but it doesn't support some common file types such as .mpg, .mobi, and .epub, and is limited to 2GB.

Also, doesn't it make sense if iPad comes with an app on iOS that can do it?

Comment: In OS X Lion, there will be "File Sharing for iPad" http://www.apple.com/macosx/lion/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried either, but there's [Cloud Connect Pro](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cloud-connect-pro/id409964704) that says you can

> View and manage files on your Windows, Mac, Linux, or other network services like Dropbox, MobileMe iDisk, Google Docs, or Box.net directly from the iPad [via SMB, AFP, FTP, SFTP or WEBDAV]

and [FileBrowser](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/filebrowser-access-files-on/id364738545) to

> [a]ccess your NAS [via CIFS/SMB] without needing to turn your computer on.

CCP is clearly more feature-rich (with e.g. integrated VNC/RDP client, printing and SMB server) but also comes with a hefty price tag ($24.99) compared to somewhat more simple FB ($3.99).
There's also an [Upgrade OS X article](http://www.upgradeosx.com/filebrowser-for-ipad-lets-you-access-computers-network-drives-shared-folders/) that discusses them both.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Desktop Connect](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/desktop-connect/id364907570?mt=8) to implement vnc based screen sharing with my Macs. That lets me see their folders just fine.
Depending on what you're doing, [Air display](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/air-display/id368158927?mt=8) might be a better choice.